# Is possible to call from a const, a function that stay in a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I would like to call the `onSignIn` function from `_signIn` const. I am wondering if that is possible somehow. I've tried to call it ad onSignIn() or Login.onSignIn() but nothing worked.

```
const _signIn = values => {
  let email = values.email;
  let password = values.password;
  console.log(email + ' ' + ' ' + password);
  return {email, password};
}

const Login = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },
  onSignIn: function() {
    var {dispatch} = this.props;
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    dispatch(loginUser(email, password)).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    });
  },
```

Here is calling `_signIn` const

```
return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 40, justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
          <Field keyboardType='email-address' label='Email' component={renderField} name='email'/> 
          <Field keyboardType='default' label='Password' component={renderFieldPass} name='password'/> 
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(_signIn)} style={{margin: 10, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{
              backgroundColor: 'steelblue', color: 'white', fontSize: 16,
              height: 37, width: 200, textAlign: 'center', padding: 10
            }}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
```

App.js

```
var App = createReactClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {}
  },
  render() {
    var renderMainView = () => {
      if (this.props.user_id) {
        return (
          <Main />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Login />
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        {renderMainView()}
        <AlertContainer/>
      </View>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You're not calling onSignIn anywhere, and it's unclear where _signIn is called.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/364724). To call a non-static function you first need an instance of that class on which you can call that function. Apart from that I don't believe that this is the correct approach. Could you provide a little more detail about the context?

Comment: @estus _signIn is called in render under onPress={} but I need the values from _signIn to pass them inside onSignIn

Comment: There's no onPress either. Please, make the code in the question reflect that. MCVE is a requirement in code-related questions.

Comment: @estus I've added the code where is called _signIn

Comment: I see. This is XY problem. You can't use onSignIn because there is no Login instance you could retrieve. Both TouchableOpacity and Login should have common parent component (e.g. Auth) that will hold `loading` state and provide methods to change it (by passing onLogin, onLogoout props to nested components, etc). This is design problem, I'd suggest to check how simple third-party auth React components work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to call `onSignIn` in the `_signIn` const, then you need to make an instance of the class and call the function from that instance.

For example

```
const _signIn = values => {
  // ... Your Data
  LoginInstance.onSignIn() // call your method here
}

const Login = createReactClass({
    // ... Your Data
  }),

const LoginInstance = new Login()
```

Comment: This code won't do anything useful. React classes aren't supposed to be instantiated manually.

Comment: Yea , but thats what @Markus Hayner was asking for specifically, need more data, to get to the correct workaround.

Comment: This is actually what I would like. This returns this error `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`

Comment: That would be the error, in your dispatch flow , you might need to provide more insight to it.

Answer (score 0):

Define `_signIn` like this:

```
function _signIn (values, onSignIn) {
  let email = values.email;
  let password = values.password;
  console.log(email + ' ' + ' ' + password);
  onSignIn.call(this)
  return {email, password};
}
```

Change your render():

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _signIn.call(this, values, this.onSignIn)} ...>
```

Comment: This method is giving me `values is not defined` inside onPress

Comment: you have to replace `values` with your username/password input value.

Comment: `values` is actually the input text. this is not a variable created by me.

Comment: could you post your `handleSubmit`?

Comment: `const { handleSubmit } = this.props;` inside render

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168782/discussion-between-markus-hayner-and-stackia).